# Nifi Toolkit add new user with certicate

Tags: ssl-certificate, apache-nifi, keystore, truststore, apache-nifi-toolkit

I'm trying to generate a new certificate for a new user, using nifi toolkit.

I already create one (for admin), using the following command:

```
/opt/nifi-toolkit-1.23.2/bin/tls-toolkit.sh standalone -n "0.0.0.0" -C "CN=sys_admin,OU=NIFI" -O -o /opt/nifi-1.23.2/certs
```

And everything is working.
Now I want to create another certificate for a new user (CN=user1,OU=NIFI), how do I do that?
Because, if I run the same command the keystore.jks and the truststore.jks will be overwritten.